# Bulk update Postgres column from python dataframe

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, bulkupdate

I am using the below python code to update postgres DB column `value`based on `Id`. This loop has to run for thousands of records and it is taking longer time.

Is there a way where I can pass array of dataframe values instead of looping each row?

```
 for i in range(0,len(df)):
        QUERY=""" UPDATE "Table" SET "value"='%s' WHERE "Table"."id"='%s'
            """ % (df['value'][i], df['id'][i])
        cur.execute(QUERY)
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on a library you use to communicate with PostgreSQL, but usually bulk inserts are much faster via [COPY FROM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html) command.

If you use psycopg2 it is as simple as following:

```
cursor.copy_from(io.StringIO(string_variable), "destination_table", columns=('id', 'value'))
```

Where **string_variable** is tab and new line delimited dataset like `1\tvalue1\n2\tvalue2\n`.

To achieve a performant bulk update I would do:

1. Create a temporary table: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table;`;
2. Insert records with **copy_from**;
3. Just update destination table with query `UPDATE destination_table SET value = t.value FROM tmp_table t WHERE id = t.id` or any [other preferred syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html)